# Newsletter feature request: Include the best answer in the newsletter

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

When I get the newsletter I have to open the link to find out what people have answered.
Why doesn't the newsletter include the best answer based on the voting in the newsletter itself? It would help to skim through the newsletter quickly. If the subscriber is interested going through other answers, then let him follow the URL.

Answer (score 2):

+1 Good point.  I second this.

However, "best answer" could be a transient attribute, unless the post is closed, locked and practically archived! Theoretically, the best answer and the answer with most upvotes need not be the same.

Plus, the comments are often more fun than the answers themselves.